# Failed to start Rabbitmq on Ubuntu server - Node is not runing

Tags: rabbitmq

I have installed Rabbitmq on my server. Suddenly I needed to remove a queue and I could not. I decided to remove and reinstall Rabbitmq but now I can not run it. I user this article https://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/install-setup-rabbitmq-ubuntu-16-04/  and got this error:

[image]
https://imgur.com/a/lL0xln6

Comment: Not sure how you removed rabbitmq but please do this run the following command to uninstall $sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove rabbitmq-server , then you can try to reinstall

Comment: still not starting

Comment: silly me but.. did you try to reboot and try ..

Comment: I can not reboot the server!  this is i got in startup_err `/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server: line 165: 22363 User defined signal 2   start_rabbitmq_server "$@"`

Comment: *NOTE*: if you follow the instructions in that article, you will most likely end up using an old version of RabbitMQ and Erlang. Please follow the instructions here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html

Answer (score -2):

Problem was related to some DNS and Hostname settings on my server. I just try to use a new server for AMQP as Saas.

Comment: Sami, both your problem and solution should be described in much more detail if you expect to help anyone else. The article to which you linked has bad advice for installing RabbitMQ and you should have used the instructions [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html). Please describe how you solved your issue in more detail - what commands you ran, and what files you edited.